# How can i subscribe/listen to chrome push notifications in angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, push-notification

I am working on building an app in angular 7 and as part of it, I have to show all browser notifications generated by our alerting system into app dashboard,
I am unsure as of now how to capture/listen to those notifications in angular app and listen/capture them as soon as they are generated and display in on the dashboard.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have checked this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/onshow but not able to implement it successfully yet..

Comment: There are actually a lot of pieces in the puzzle. Do you have a PubSub service in place that publishes PushNotifications? You might also want to check [this out](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-push-notifications/)

Comment: the notifications I am talking about are generated by third-party website on which I have no control, but create alerts for us and notify us via notification,

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like EventSource on angular side to access server side events.

```
  var source = new EventSource('http://localhost:8080/stream/employees');

         source.onmessage = (event) =>{
          var data = event.data
           console.log(data)
           this.toast.show('User is '+ data.firstname)
       }
```

Above is an Basic example to access the server side events and display them on the Angular side.

I would require additional info from your side how the data is being pushed from the server side and what have you been trying to show the notifications on the Angular UI.

Comment: alerts are notified by third party website via chrome desktop notification